# Широковещательная рассылка. Узнать количество серверов в сети с одинаковыми позывными

Tags: c++, winsock

В локальной сети находятся несколько компьютеров, одни из них сервера. При запуске нового сервера, он выполняет широковещательную рассылку для проверки, сколько серверов в сети с позывным как у него, и выводит количество этих серверов на консоль.

Позывной - обычная срока.

Как это реализовать без потоков и наиболее просто?

recvfrom приостанавливает программу в ожидании ответа, но я же не знаю сколько серверов в сети и сколько мне придется выполнить этих recv.

Comment: Как я бы это делал. При старте сервер посылает сообщение "кто главный". Если никто не отвечает какое-то время - главным стает сам и рассылает сообщение о этом. Если "главный" есть, то он получив сообщение, обновляет свои списки и отправляет назад вопрошающему информацию о состоянии сети. Осталось решить проблему с конкуренцией "главных", но тут есть метод "хулигана" - у кого айпи меньше (если сравнивать как число или строку), того и тапки.

Comment: в posix есть функция select которая позволяет ждать данных на нескольких сокетах и при этом ей можно задавать таймаут. в winapi наверняка найдется что то подобное